# Hebrew or Yiddish name for English "Louis"

Tags: names, yiddish

What are common Hebrew or Yiddish names for the English name Louis?
Would this be Loeb or Levi or others?

Comment: Yiddish or Hebrew ? Your example gives both.

Comment: My apologies.  I'm poorly educated in this area. I would have been happy to hear a name in either language or both.

Comment: @Susan A pity this question was closed. I would really like to know the answer. My great-grandfather, a Levi, was named Louis in English. His Hebrew name was ליב. I am desperate to figure out whether this name should be pronounced "Lieb," "Leib," or "Lev." We lost the family tradition of the pronunciation. My grandfather, who is still alive B"H, and whose name includes his father's name, doesn't know how that part of his name should be pronounced.

Comment: @SAH but why do you think it should be reopened?

Comment: @רבות מחשבות I think it's within scope. Lots of "names" questions stay open. We even have a tag for them. Such questions are most definitely about Judaism and nothing else --unless we imagine an Onomastics.SE (not inconceivable someday, I suppose) -- at least to the extent that language is about Judaism and within scope (which it is, according to the official parameters). רבות מחשבות@

Comment: רבות מחשבות@ More basically, I have never understood the utility of stringently restricting the scope of this or any site in our era of modern computing. רבות מחשבות@ @רבות מחשבות@ (Sorry, how does one tag you, actually?)

Comment: @SAH whether another site exists for a certain question neither supports not prevents its closure here as off-topic. That's actually a Stack Exchange standard, not just Mi Yodeya.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות There is ongoing discussion here (https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4225/questions-about-the-meaning-source-of-yiddish-names ) about whether name questions are on-topic. The moderator who closed this question holds that they are not. It seems many others hold that they are.

Comment: @msh210 Fair enough. That part was a detail anyway

Comment: Check this out:  https://academicworks.cuny.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2840&context=gc_etds   especially beginning page 51.

Comment: http://www.avotaynu.com/allbooks.htm   offers books on Jewish given and surnames

Comment: @JJLL This is absolutely fantastic; thank you so much. It makes me think my grandfather's name was probably Leib. Also thrilled to find that one passenger on the ship had the same unusual Hebrew name and kinui pair as I do

Comment: I’m glad the info was helpful SAH

Answer (score 4):

YMMV, but the [Previous Lubavitcher Rebbe](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15614&st=pierre&pgnum=133) wrote that there was a "Pierre Louis" (an assimilated Jew from France) who visited Harki. The town was Chassidic, and it happened that one of the townsmen visited the Baal Shem Tov in the interim.

> The Baal Shem Tov then instructed Rabbi Nissan to go to Pierre Louis and tell him that he was of Jewish descent; that his name was really Pesach Tzvi, after his mother's grandfather; "Pierre" being the French name for ''Pesach," and **"Louis" for "Levi,"** for he was a Levi.

Comment: Where does Tzvi come from in the story?

Comment: @waf it looks like his real name was pesach tzvi halevi.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin How did the Previous Rebbe know about the "Tzvi" in his name? That is the part I don't get, if the "Louis" is supposed to reflect "Levi."

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Also, please see my comment on the original question. If you have any insights on that, I'd greatly appreciate hearing them.